# Combining multiple SPF records

Tags: spf

I am using Yandex Mail and Firebase. I send corporate mails through Yandex and application sends registration, verification, etc. mails through Firebase. Both of them need following SPF records:

```
v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.net
v=spf1 include:_spf.firebasemail.com ~all
```

Only single SPF record is allowed so how can I combine both records into single one? I checked similar questions but none of them has a record with `redirect` directive.

I tried the following and according to this tool http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html it works, but I don't know if it is correct.

```
v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.net include:_spf.firebasemail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

From the RFC:

> For clarity, any "redirect" modifier SHOULD appear as the very last
>      term in a record.

Personally I would rather do something like the following:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.yandex.ru include:_spf.firebasemail.com ~all
```

Or change the end to `-all` if you want to be more strict on email not coming from one of the listed locations. The only downside of using `-all` is that some mail providers don't handle forwarding correctly (don't use SRS) and so you can find your emails being rejected if a recipient has them forwarded and the final destination is configured to reject on SPF fail - Consider the following

1. You email from me@mydomain.com to recipient@hisdomain.com.
2. The recipient has configured his email to be forwarded to recipient@gmail.com. His ISP just forward the message on without changing the envelope sender address. (The from address used in SMTP communication, not the address in the actual email headers).
3. gmail.com see an email coming in from hisisp.com, but with your sender address, and hisisp.com isn't listed as a valid source in the SPF record.

A lot of ISP's don't actually reject email on SPF fail, but then some do.

Comment: I used `redirect` directive because Yandex suggests me to do so but if your version is better I would sue it.

Answer (score 1):

Google translated:

The recommendation of Yandex itself is how to act in this case:

If you want to send messages not only from Yandex servers, specify additional servers in the following format: "v = spf1 ip4: IP-1 ip4: IP-2 ip4: IP-3 include: _spf.yandex.net ~ all". Where IP-1, IP-2, IP-3 - IP-addresses of additional servers.

Proof here

Пруф тут https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/set-mail/spf.html

Answer (score 0):

here it is (without blanks after ip4:)
[yandex spf with both ip and redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyWHI.png)